# Error handling WebRTC offer: Nest API error: 500: INTERNAL: Internal error encountered.: Internal Server Error

Tags: google-api, nest, home-assistant

Expected:

Tried accessing a WebRTC stream via the smartdevicemanagement API.

Actual:

Instead of getting a WebRTC stream, I got a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error response.

Description:

Using my HomeAssistant integration, which has been working just fine for my old Nest Camera (pre-Google) camera via Google Home as well as my new Google Nest Thermostat for months, I just authorized access to the integration and my new Nest Outdoor Camera (battery, with attached power cable) and the camera appeared in HomeAssistant.

However, upon trying to view the camera I get the following errors in the debug log:

```
2023-11-16 18:11:10.548 DEBUG (MainThread) [google_nest_sdm.auth] request[post]=https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/32b...snip...ddc/devices/AVP...snip...V1A:executeCommand
2023-11-16 18:11:10.548 DEBUG (MainThread) [google_nest_sdm.auth] request[post json]={'command': 'sdm.devices.commands.CameraLiveStream.GenerateWebRtcStream', 'params': {'offerSdp': 'v=0\r\no=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-99.0 7796251033926144831 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 9C:13:7B:0E:...snip...6A:B5:DC:C8\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=msid-semantic:WMS *\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=recvonly\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:2/recvonly urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:csrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1\r\na=fmtp:101 0-15\r\na=ice-pwd:b652c2af1d149748943ba0e9ed110f2c\r\na=ice-ufrag:46c3eea7\r\na=mid:0\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000/1\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=ssrc:1787629243 cname:{b9a...snip...a05}\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 124 121 125 126 127 97 98\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=recvonly\r\na=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:6/recvonly http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay\r\na=extmap:7 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1\r\na=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1\r\na=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60\r\na=fmtp:124 apt=120\r\na=fmtp:121 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60\r\na=fmtp:125 apt=121\r\na=fmtp:127 apt=126\r\na=fmtp:98 apt=97\r\na=ice-pwd:b65...snip...f2c\r\na=ice-ufrag:46c3eea7\r\na=mid:1\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:120 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:121 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:126 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:97 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000\r\na=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000\r\na=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:126 H264/90000\r\na=rtpmap:127 rtx/90000\r\na=rtpmap:97 H264/90000\r\na=rtpmap:98 rtx/90000\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=ssrc:3653470488 cname:{b9a...snip...a05}\r\nm=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=ice-pwd:b65...snip...f2c\r\na=ice-ufrag:46c3eea7\r\na=mid:2\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=sctp-port:5000\r\na=max-message-size:1073741823\r\na=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 40e...snip...cb2.local 49161 typ host\r\na=candidate:1 1 TCP 2105524479 40e...snip...cb2.local 9 typ host tcptype active\r\na=\r\na=candidate:1 1 TCP 2105524479 40e...snip...cb2.local 9 typ host tcptype active\r\na=candidate:1 2 TCP 2105524478 40e...snip...cb2.local 9 typ host tcptype active\r\na=\r\na=candidate:1 1 TCP 2105524479 40e...snip...cb2.local 9 typ host tcptype active\r\na=candidate:1 2 TCP 2105524478 40e...snip...cb2.local 9 typ host tcptype active\r\na=\r\n'}}
2023-11-16 18:11:11.346 ERROR (MainThread) [homeassistant.components.camera] Error handling WebRTC offer: Nest API error: Error from API: 500: INTERNAL: Internal error encountered.: Internal Server Error
```